# Pronunciation of "Nevada"

Tags: pronunciation, proper-nouns, vowels, spanish

People in the state of Nevada insist that it should be pronounced /nəˈvædə/ (with the vowel of TRAP)—this "issue" always comes up during campaigns—while much of the country typically pronounces it /nəˈvɑːdə/ (with the vowel of PALM). Is one correct over the other or are they both equal?

Comment: Recorded pronunciation is [/nɪˈvɑːdə/](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Nevada?q=Nevada)

Comment: FWIW, I grew up in California and we always pronounced it with the TRAP vowel—i.e., correctly.

Comment: *Nevada* has the *a* of *FATHER*, not of *PALM*. *PALM* has the vowel of *Paul*.

Comment: @Matt: that's the Oxford Dictionaries Online's British pronunciation. Their American pronunciation is /nəˈvædə/ or /nəˈvɑdə/, which corresponds to what I hear in the U.S.

Comment: @tchrist: PALM has the vowel of FATHER in the U.K. and parts of the U.S.

Comment: @PeterShor Wouldn’t need two different lexical sets if they were always the same. CLOTH and PALM are the same, though, like in *raw*.

Comment: Are FATHER and PALM different lexical sets? See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set). You're right, though: given their pronunciation in the U.S., they should be.

Answer (score 10):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevada),

> The name "Nevada" **comes from the Spanish Nevada [neˈβaða]**, meaning "snow-covered", after the Sierra Nevada ("snow-covered mountains") mountain range.
>
> Nevadans normally pronounce the second syllable of their state name using **the /æ/ vowel of "bad"**. Many from outside the Western United States pronounce it **with the /ɑː/ vowel of "father" /nəˈvɑːdə/**. Although the latter pronunciation is closer to the Spanish pronunciation, it is not the pronunciation preferred by locals.

You can hear the difference on [Forvo which has a number of users](http://www.forvo.com/word/nevada/#en) from around the US pronouncing *Nevada*, including one person (dgrahame) from Reno. In terms of right and wrong (as these things go), considering its [Spanish roots](http://www.forvo.com/word/nevada/#es), */nəˈvɑːdə/* is more "right" than */nəˈvædə/*. But, as George Dubya discovered, when in Rome ...

> Notably, George W. Bush made this faux pas during his campaign for the 2004 U.S. Presidential Election. Vindication later came when President Bush campaigned at the Reno-Sparks Convention Center on June 18, 2004. The president opened his talk by proclaiming that "It's great to be here in Nevada /nəˈˈvædə/," emphasizing the correct 'a' – the crowd roared its approval when he light-heartedly noted, "You didn't think I'd get it right, did ya?" Bush subsequently carried the state in the election.